# Difference between 2 selects in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one data table:

```
--------------------
ID |  user | Value
--------------------
1  |  1    | 1
--------------------
2  |  1    | 2
--------------------
3  |  2    | 3
--------------------
4  |  2    | 2
--------------------
5  |  3    | 4
--------------------
6  |  3    | 2
--------------------
```

I would like to SELECT all rows where value is different comparing to user 1 so the result would be rows with IDs 3 (value is 3) and 5 (value is 2)

I would do something like this (will call it A)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = 1
```

and get all the rows from user 1. Than I would select (will call it B)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user != 1
```

and get all other rows. And than I would compare them `WHERE A.value != B.value`.

I'm stuck on how to merge everything together...

Please help!

Comment: OP has mentioned the desired result in the question. "so the result would be rows with IDs 3 (value is 3) and 5 (value is 2)". I believe OP has incorrectly written and "5 (value is 2)", it should have been "and 5 (value is 4)" as row 5 has value=4

Comment: @MarkByers as i understand he wants to get all data from table where the value not equal any of the values that the user has qoute from OP : "so the result would be rows with IDs 3 (value is 3) and 5 (value is 2)"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE value NOT IN ( SELECT value FROM table WHERE user = 1)
```

Answer (score 29):

The relational operator is indeed 'difference', Oracle has the keyword `MINUS`, Standard SQL has the keyword `EXCEPT` e.g.

```
SELECT value 
  FROM table 
EXCEPT
SELECT value 
  FROM table 
 WHERE user = 1;
```

Sadly, MySQL doesn't have any such an operator, you have to use other SQL constructs e.g. `NOT IN <table expression>`:

```
SELECT value 
  FROM table
 WHERE value NOT IN ( SELECT value
                        FROM table
                       WHERE user = 1 );
```

Answer (score 4):

`select * from table where value not in (select value from table where user = 1);`